# Lexical `this` and Timeout

Tags: javascript

Im reading through the YDKJS books and I thought I understood lexical `this` for the most part.

However there is a section with code that shows this:

```
var obj = {
    id: "awesome",
    cool: function coolFn() {
        console.log( this.id );
    }
};

var id = "not awesome";

obj.cool(); // awesome

setTimeout( obj.cool, 100 ); // not awesome
```

Ok so the first `obj.cool()` makes sense of course....but why is the `setTimeout` printing `not awesome`.....I mean it's still calling `obj.cool()` which `this` refers to it's own objects `id`?

Or does setTimeout get called as another function that calls `obj.cool()`? but even in that case (Which I tried calling `obj.cool()` inside another function that also had an `id` property and it still printed the right one......so why would the `this` change with setTimeout?

Comment: Because `this` is pointing to `window` inside `setTimeout` and any variable defined outside function becomes a part of global scope

Comment: Read documentation first before asking https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Comment: 'this' depends on the function invocation. calling it like obj.method() will set 'this' to be obj. whereas calling it like method() will set 'this' to the global scope
More info here: https://rainsoft.io/gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript/

Comment: Each function has a *context* in which it is invoked. When you're invoking `obj.cool()` directly, the context (`this`) is indeed `obj`. But, when you're passing a reference to a function that happens to be assigned on `obj`, the context would be determined by the (well...) the context in which it is being executed, and in your case, `setTimeout` would invoke it in a global context, hence `this === window`.

Comment: Uh, [`this` is **not** lexical](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/1048572)?

Comment: Here is a way around it but, you need to use a constructor to make objects so you cannot use literals: https://jsfiddle.net/85m3geob/1/

Comment: As Rajesh mentioned, this is pointing to window object inside setTimeout. Do use bind method to bind the required object to the function, `setTimeout( obj.cool.bind(obj), 100 ); ` Learn function methods suchas `bind`, `call` and `apply` to understand what is happening http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-apply-call-and-bind-methods-are-essential-for-javascript-professionals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the OBJ.COOL function is passed by reference, you are not actually passing the context object with it. The function gets new invocation context and executes on the WINDOW object, which now has a property called ID which was defined earlier.

Comment: Ah, so because it's being passed as a parameter it's not passing the context. But just calling it in global space keeps the context intact.